# how to access functions outside of web3 scope?

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I'm building a react-web3 app.

How do I access methods that are out of scope like this.setState within a web3 method?

```
componentDidMount() {
    var events = contractInstance.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
        events.watch(function(error, result){
            this.setState({result: result})
        });
    }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I can easily do so with the filter method (`web3.eth.filter()`) but not with events

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function as your callback:

```
   events.watch((error, result)=>{
        this.setState({result: result})
    });
```

For all arrow functions, 'this' will take on the same value of 'this' in the enclosing context. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Notice how if you do setState directly in your componentDidMount(), or in the context of componentWillMount() for example, it works perfectly. In those places, 'this' refers to your component object, as you would expect. But once you define a callback function, the value of 'this' inside that function could change depending on how your callback is used. So to force the value of 'this' inside your callback to be what you want, you can use the arrow function as mentioned. Because for all arrow functions, 'this' will take on the same value of 'this' in the enclosing context.

Alternatively, you could use bind:

```
   events.watch(function(error, result){
       this.setState({result: result})
   }.bind(this));
```